# sum of values of two lists in java

Tags: java, arraylist, sum

I am working on a java project and I am having a problem. I want to have the sum of two lists `a` and `b` in list `c` but I don't know how to do that. 
I want `a.add(3) +b.add(4)` should be in next list `c` where the value should be 7
similarly for 5+2=6 
              1+(-4)=-3
any suggestion and help would be appreciated

Code:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;  
import java.util.List; 

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Integer> a = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        List<Integer> b = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        List<Integer> three= new ArrayList<Integer>();

        a.add(3);
        a.add(5);
        a.add(1);
        a.add(-2);

        b.add(1);
        b.add(2);
        b.add(-4);
        b.add(3);


    }

}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simply :

```
for (int i = 0; i < a.size(); i++) {
        result.add(a.get(i) + b.get(i));
}
```

Answer (score 20):

No elementary question is truly complete without an answer that uses Streams. Here you go:

```
List<Integer> result = IntStream.range(0, a.size())
         .mapToObj(i -> a.get(i) + b.get(i))
         .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 2):

While using

```
for (int i = 0; i < a.size(); i++)
{
    result.add(a.get(i) + b.get(i));
}
```

As per Salah's answer is correct, I don't think it's the best option for you.

Not knowing how to add up 2 arrays shows a fundamental lack of understanding.  Just asking for code to paste on the end of your function won't help anyone, **especially** not you.  Learning computer science is all about **experimenting** and learning by trial and error.

[image]

I suggest you read [this page](http://codingbat.com/doc/java-array-loops.html), try to write **your own** code, and come back here with questions if your code doesn't work.  You will learn a lot more that way.

If you have read the page and still don't understand, don't feel bad.   Comment on my answer and I will write a short explanation of how Java for loops and arrays work.

Comment: Actually, geo is way off.

Comment: really?  It's been a while since I did any java development.  Thanks for letting me know.  Edited......  For my education, can you explain why this is?  I just dug up some of my old java code, and I do indeed use this function.  Is ListUtils deprecated?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with ListUtils (well... nothing *seriously* wrong), it just has nothing to do with this question. See my comment on geo's post.

Comment: "This is their intersection subtracted from their union."  Oh gosh.  I need to learn how to read english.  Maybe I should visit the english learners stack exchange ;)     thanks.